# Can I change the Version Name of a package?

Tags: managed-package, package

I've already uploaded my package, and I can't seem to find anywhere to change the name of it. The version is fine, it's just the name I'd like to edit. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't change the version name once uploaded. You can upload a new version then deprecate the older version, but I assume that the solution is likely overkill in your situation. However, I do know that support has some (limited) ability to modify a version after it has been uploaded, so they may be able to honor your request if you submit a case. The most common attribute change is reverting a release version back to a beta version, but that's not to say they can't modify other attributes, although this isn't documented anywhere, so your best bet is to ask.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the version name.
Even Salesforce Support cannot help you on this one.
As sfdcfox mentioned, upload a new version with correct name.

> I want to inform you here that after upload you will not be able to change the release version name of the package . There is no proper setting to change the release version name of the package after upload.
> The only way to change is , you have to Upload your package second time to change the version number.